# Redireccionar a página si se cumple condición con Ajax y SweetAlert2

Tags: ajax, sweetalert2

Estoy buscando ayuda por favor. Resulta que estoy desarrollando una pagina web, en la cual las personas pagan y adquieren membresías para clases de yoga. A través de *Ajax* realizo una consulta a la base de datos para saber si el usuario ya compro dicha membresía. Al dar *click* al botón de pagar, este lo redirige a la página del *checkout*. Pero mi intención es que si el usuario ya adquirió dicha membresía, salte una alerta que diga que ya pago por ella. De lo contrario, que lo redirija a la pagina del perfil *checkout*.

Hasta ahora no puedo hacer que la condición `if` haga su trabajo. Si alguien me puede echar una manita, por favor Soy casi nula para *JavaScript*.

También he probado la respuesta con *console.log* y recibo bien la respuesta. Sino hay respuesta, llega `false`.

```
event.preventDefault();

var datos = new FormData();

datos.append("idUsuario", idUsuario);
datos.append("idClase", idClase);

    Swal.fire({
            icon: 'success',
            title: '¡ agregaras un nuevo servicio en tu perfil !',
            showCancelButton: true,
            cancelButtonColor: '#f9a253',
            confirmButtonColor: '#089eb0',
            cancelButtonText: '¡no gracias!',
            confirmButtonText: '¡Ir a mi perfil!'
        }).then((result) => {
        if (result.value) {

            $.ajax({

                url:rutaOculta+"ajax/carrito.ajax.php",
                method:"POST",
                data: datos,
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData:false,

                success: function(respuesta){


                    if(respuesta != false){

                        Swal.fire({
                            icon: "warning",
                            title: "¡Ya esta inscrito en esta clase!",
                            text: "",
                            showConfirmButton: true,

                          });

                    }else{

                        window.location = rutaOculta+"perfil";

                    }  
                }       
            });
        }
    });
```

Si doy click a una clase (servicio) que no he adquirido (pagado) me debe redirigir a la página de perfil para hacer el pago... pero esto no sucede.

Esto ocurre...

Doy click al servicio y salta la primera ventana modal...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

luego tengo la opción hacer click en el botón "ir a mi perfil" que me tendría que dejar pasar a esa dirección, ya que no tengo ese servicio comprado, o más bien dicho almacenado en mi BD. Pero no lo hace, al contrario, salta la nueva ventana modal indicando que ya estoy inscrita en esa clase cuando no es así.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se puede apreciar también que la respuesta de Ajax en la consola es false..

Si hago este mismo procedimiento con un servicio que ya he comprado funciona, pero es por que realmente es la lógica del error que ya esta incorporado.

Comment: Puedes mostrarnos tu código de `ajax/carrito.ajax.php` ?

Comment: @JonathanOrta ahí edite el código y agregue el archivo de ajax/carrito.ajax.php

Comment: Gracias, puedes agregar tambien el contenido de la funcion `ctrVerificarClasePago`, por la respuesta que muestras, parece que recibes un string false, si deseas ver mas respuestas de la API, revisa la pestaña Network de las herramientas de desarrollador, con esto puedes ver que te envia el server, puedes agregarlo tambien para averiguar que ocurre.

Comment: @JonathanOrta ya se lo que me trae la respuesta.. y si, debe venir en false la respuesta si el servicio no existe... de lo contrario me entrega los valores registrados.. más abajo cree otro comentario con unas fotos del proceso.

Answer (score 2):

Tomando en cuenta las opciones de respuesta que tienes y el tratamiento de información del backend, muy posiblemente tienes que tranformar el dato obtenido, ya que recibes json, por lo tanto, cambia tu operación de javascript de esta forma.

```
success: function(respuesta){
    let server_response = JSON.parse(respuesta);
    //if(server_response !== false) { Intenta revisar si la respuesta es un string o un booleano
    if(server_response !== 'false') {
        Swal.fire({
            icon: "warning",
            title: "¡Ya esta inscrito en esta clase!",
            text: "",
            showConfirmButton: true,
        });
    } else {
        window.location = rutaOculta+"perfil";
    }
}
```

Comment: No funciona con esos cambios, no salta la ventana modal, y pasa directamente a la pagina de perfil saltandoce la condición if. También tengo un console.log('respuesta', respuesta) y tampoco lo muestra.. al contrario me arroja un error:  SyntaxError: redeclaration of formal parameter respuestachecked.js:148:28note: Previously declared at line 145, column 38... que es linea de:  let response = JSON.parse(respuesta);

Comment: Se redeclaró una variable que ya tenias, revisa mi respuesta editada, cambié `let response` por `let server_response

Comment: Gracias por tu tiempo Jonathan... pero aún no funciona. Pero ahora si sale la ventana modal, y la respuesta del `console.log('respuesta', respuesta)` me dice: `respuesta falsefalse`. (Como debe ser en un servicio que no he adquirido) Ahora también la consola me muestra el error: `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 6 of the JSON data`

Comment: Entonces tu respuesta esta malformada, ya que recibes `falsefalse`, lo cual es un string, y así deberás compararlo, sin embargo no es lo correcto, como te había comentado, el problema viene desde la función `ctrVerificarClasePago`, ¿puedes mostrarla?

Comment: `class ControladorCarrito{static public function ctrVerificarClasePago($datos){

  $tabla = "compras";

  $respuesta = ModeloCarrito::mdlVerificarClasePago($tabla, $datos);

  return $respuesta;

 }}`

Comment: Necesitas los datos del modelo también?

Comment: El comentario anterior puedes agregarlo a tu pregunta, asi se le da mejor seguimiento por si alguien mas puede ayudarte, como se ve el `ControladorCarrito`, es necesario tambien ver `ModeloCarrito::mdlVerificarClasePago`

Comment: Ok lo agrego ahora.. gracias.!!

Comment: Ya lo agregue... me daba problemas para que se vea bien el código al incluirlo en la edición, por ello se vera algo desordenado... pero no me dejaba hacerlo de otra forma... ojala se pueda resolver mi problema.

Comment: Cuando el elemento no existe deberia devolverte `null` y no `false`, revisa tambien la pestaña Red, al momento de ejecutar el primer modelo, para ver la respuesta directa del server.

Comment: Ya encontré la solución. El problema no era el código que tenia en el archivo javascript que publique en un principio, El problema lo tenia en el archivo `carrito.ajax.php`  ya que tenia dos funciones publicas usando la misma clase que se dirige al archivo javascript ... A pesar que tenían nombres totalmente diferentes incluso en sus variables igual colacionaban los datos. Por eso en la consola me salia `respuesta falsefalse` (dos veces false) y me tenia que dar `respuesta false` (una ves) Gracias igual por tu atención y ayuda a esta novata. Saludos.!

Answer (score 0):

Hola en ensaya en el condicional esto

```
if(respuesta === "true")
```

Comment: No funciona.. tal vez el problema, es que tengo mal configurado el SweetAlert... la verdad ya no se que pensar... me tiene frustrada.

Comment: que navegador estás utilizando?..mira la consola web en herramientas de desarrollador(presionar tecla F12 en el navegador) para que mires que sucede al presionar la acción, ahí te das cuenta si es problema de referencias del sweetalert, y puedes enviar la captura para poder ver que error sale

Comment: No tengo errores de js en la consola, eso ya lo verifique. y en 4 navegadores que uso no tengo problemas

Comment: bueno, mi primera recomendación es que utilices sweetalert versión 1 https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/#advanced-examples , en ésta pagina están los ejemplos y descarga las librerías

Comment: No gracias, no lo veo viable, tendría que cambiar mas de 80 modales en mis controladores... Gracias!